# Share non top level folder on dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Ive got a folder in my dropbox account located at :

`Dropbox / Projects / Project Name`

That i want to share with another dropbox user so that they can collaboratively access / share files in this folder.

Am i able to share this folder as its not a top level folder, other than as a link ?

Im running dropbox on OSX 10.13.6 and the latest version of Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Drop Box Business account to do that.

> Quote : No. You can’t share a folder that’s inside of a shared folder
>   unless you’re using a Dropbox Business account.

You can use Team folders and share inside Team Folders

Reference:  https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/share-inside-folder

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the receiving party needs a business account also ? I couldnt see anything about that in the linked docs

Comment: If not using Team folders then yes, the receiving party need the Business Version as well

Comment: I can't seem to find where Sam actually mentioned that this folder _was_ inside another shared folder.

Comment: I assumed that project / project name (up above) was a folder inside project that was to be shared.

Comment: To clarify the project folder is shared already also with others